How to optimise a recursive SQL query to find the cheapest path
I'm working on a recursive SQL query in PostgreSQL to find the minimum cost required to reach various cities from Montreal. The data follows a directed acyclic graph (DAG) structure, where each flight connection is represented in a Flights table with columns src (source city), dst (destination city), and cost (flight cost).
For example:
Route 1: Montreal → Toronto → LA, total cost: $2000
Route 2: Montreal → Chicago → LA, total cost: $1800

In this case, the query should return only the cheapest route to LA with a total cost of $1800.
The query I've written finds the cheapest paths, but I'm looking for guidance on optimizing it further.
Specifically, I want to:

Ensure the recursive query filters paths to maintain only the minimum total cost for each destination.
Avoid revisiting connections (or cities) that have already been included in a path.

Any suggestions on improving the performance or structure of this query?
Thanks for your help!
WITH RECURSIVE CheapestFlight AS 
(
    SELECT src, dst, cost AS total_price
    FROM Flights
    WHERE src = 'Montreal'
    UNION
    SELECT cf.src, f.dst, cf.total_price + f.cost AS total_price
    FROM CheapestFlight cf
    INNER JOIN Flights f ON f.src = cf.dst
)
SELECT dst as destination, total_price
FROM CheapestFlight cf
WHERE total_price = (SELECT MIN(total_price)
                     FROM CheapestFlight
                     WHERE dst = cf.dst)


You probably want to research Dijkstra's algorithm - or other similar path finding algorithms

Please provide some sample data of the affected tables and the expected result of your query

Does your query ever finish? You might need to exclude cycles. Other than that, you could use DISTINCT ON in the main query rather than use a subquery.

I would eliminate cycles in the recursive query and use DISTINCT ON in the main query:
WITH RECURSIVE CheapestFlight AS 
(
    SELECT src, dst,
           ARRAY[dst] AS path,
           cost AS total_price
    FROM Flights
    WHERE src = 'Montreal'
    UNION
    SELECT cf.src, f.dst,
           cf.path || f.dst AS path,
           cf.total_price + f.cost AS total_price
    FROM CheapestFlight cf
    INNER JOIN Flights f ON f.src = cf.dst
    WHERE NOT ARRAY[f.dst] <@ cf.path
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (dst) 
       dst as destination,
       total_price
FROM CheapestFlight cf
ORDER BY dst, total_price;

But that's certainly not the best possible algorithm out there.

With table flights like here ...



src
dst
cost




Montreal
Toronto
500


Montreal
Chicago
800


Montreal
LA
2100


Toronto
LA
1500


Toronto
Chicago
400


Chicago
LA
1000



... you could get your paths and costs combining a few cte-s ...
WITH
  --  sources with the list of the destinations
  dirs AS
    ( Select src, STRING_AGG(dst, '-') as destinations
      From   flights
      Group By src
      Order By src
    ),
  --  path combinations per source
  paths AS
    ( Select     f.src, f.dst, f.cost
      From       flights f
      Left Join  dirs d ON( d.src = f.src And 
                            Position('-' || dst || '-' IN '-' || destinations || '-') > 0 )
    ), 
  -- costs
  costs AS 
    ( Select      p.*, 
                  p2.src as src_2, p2.dst as dst_2, Coalesce(p2.cost, 0) as cost_2, 
                  p3.src as src_3, p3.dst as dst_3, Coalesce(p3.cost, 0) as cost_3, 
                  p.src || 
                  Case When p2.src Is Not Null Then '-' || p2.src 
                  Else '-' 
                  End ||
                    Case When p2.dst Is Not Null And p3.dst Is Not Null 
                              Then '-' || p2.dst || '-' || p3.dst 
                         When p2.dst Is Not Null And p3.dst Is Null
                         Then '-' || p2.dst
                    Else p.dst 
                    End as path, 
                  p.cost + Coalesce(p2.cost, 0) + Coalesce(p3.cost, 0) as total_cost
      From        paths p
      Left Join   paths p2 ON(p2.src = p.dst)
      Left Join   paths p3 ON(p2.src = p.dst And p3.src = p2.dst) 
    ), 
  paths_costs AS 
  --  paths and costs for all relations - resultset is filtered in Main SQL below - for Montreal-LA ( the cheapest one ) 
    ( Select   src, Substr(path, (Length(path) - Position('-' IN Reverse(path))) + 2) as dst, 
               path, total_cost
      From     costs
    )  

--      M a i n    S Q L :
--      filtered for Montreal-LA and the lowest total_cost
SELECT   pc.src, pc.dst, pc.path, pc.total_cost
FROM     paths_costs pc
WHERE    src = 'Montreal' And dst = 'LA' And
         pc.total_cost  = ( Select Min(total_cost) From paths_costs Where src = pc.src And dst = pc.dst )

R e s u l t :



src
dst
path
total_cost




Montreal
LA
Montreal-Chicago-LA
1800



NOTE: This will work for paths with maximum of 2 flight changes (4 airports from src to dst - both included)
fiddle
The costs cte resultset containes all you need for different reportings:
... ... ...
Select   *   From  costs;

cte costs resultset:



src
dst
cost
src_2
dst_2
cost_2
src_3
dst_3
cost_3
path
total_cost




Montreal
Toronto
500
Toronto
Chicago
400
Chicago
LA
1000
Montreal-Toronto-Chicago-LA
1900


Montreal
Toronto
500
Toronto
LA
1500
null
null
0
Montreal-Toronto-LA
2000


Montreal
Chicago
800
Chicago
LA
1000
null
null
0
Montreal-Chicago-LA
1800


Montreal
LA
2100
null
null
0
null
null
0
Montreal-LA
2100


Toronto
LA
1500
null
null
0
null
null
0
Toronto-LA
1500


Toronto
Chicago
400
Chicago
LA
1000
null
null
0
Toronto-Chicago-LA
1400


Chicago
LA
1000
null
null
0
null
null
0
Chicago-LA
1000



